# <video> playback performance on huge files

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm working on a webapp which will run on a specific system which we also build. The app will run in fullscreen / kiosk-mode Mozilla Firefox / Google Chrome and one of the features in this app is that it will popup a video `<video>` when the app is 30 seconds inactive. The display consists of 3 HD TV's so the fullscreen browser will span those (with extra bezel) which makes it 5892 x 1080 big.

When running the video (5892 x 1080) in VLC the video runs as a dream. Though when running it on Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, it soon becomes a sluggish video.

Are there any settings I might adjust on the system to make it render as quick as VLC?